# Socket In Binding Android Service

Tags: android, sockets, service

I have a Service that has to wait command from a Server. Now i need to create a socket from the start until the Service's life end. I thinked to make it in onCreate() method and keep the Socket in a private variable and use it in BindService() after but it doesn't work. Where is my error or where are errors? Thanks all.

```
package com.example.testercomunicationandroidservlet;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.Data;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class BindService extends Service {

    public BindService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    public void onCreate()
        {
            try {
                    Log.i("BindService", "Service Started");
                    this.socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 1500);
                    this.input = new DataInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
                    this.output = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
                    Log.i("Test Server/Android Communication", "Socket: " + this.socket.getInetAddress().toString());
                    TelephonyManager  tm= (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                    this.output.writeUTF(tm.getDeviceId());

                    Log.i("Inviato IMEI: ", tm.getDeviceId());
                }
            catch (UnknownHostException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    private Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream input;
    private DataOutputStream output;
}
```

LogCat

```
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295): C: Error
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(Native Method)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(OSNetworkSystem.java:115)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:244)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:219)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:781)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:316)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at com.example.betacomunicate_clientandroid.TCPClient.run(TCPClient.java:53)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at com.example.betacomunicate_clientandroid.MyActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:89)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at com.example.betacomunicate_clientandroid.MyActivity$connectTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:1)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-18 15:21:22.633: E/TCP(295):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure :

- both android and the server are on the same network ? (the are on the same lan, with a rooter that doesn't isolate DHCP clients)
- android has internet access (adb shell ping kde.org)
- android can actually reach the server ? (adb shell telnet 10.02.2.2 1500)
- there is a server on 10.0.2.2:1500 ? (look with a browser or telnet 10.02.2.2 1500 from you computer)

the only thing that is wrong up to now is that android can't connect to your server.

And finally, but that's more a design choice, are you sure you wanna use such a custom protocole ? Nothing like HTTP / REST / JSON / PROTOBUF ?